# Create dynamically a XSD for a form

Tags: orbeon, xforms

In the Form Builder tool from Orbeon it's possible to specify a schema by uploading a XSD file.

But if we don't have the schema or we are too lazy to c reate it,  is it possible to create dynamically the schema ?

The schema is needed for the use of the form datas in other systems like a Business Object universe.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Orbeon Forms doesn't automatically generate schemas based on the forms you create in Form Builder; instead, as you noted, it is designed to consume a schema that you already have.

However, there are tools that do just that. You can find some mentioned on the answer to this question on [how to generate an XSD schema from an XML instance document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74879/any-tools-to-generate-an-xsd-schema-from-an-xml-instance-document).

Answer (score -1):

I am working on my own project called XsdFormEditor. Application will be able to show any XSD as a form in WinForms (95% done), Web (using Asp.Net MVC, 0% done), WPF (0% done). Idea is to load any XSD file, show it to user as a form, let user input some data and save data as XML. User will be also able to load default values to form from XML file. You can find it here: https://github.com/janstafa/XsdFormEditor

Comment: We'd prefer that you not copy and paste the same answer advertising your GitHub project in multiple questions. If the questions are indeed asking the same thing, answer one of them and flag the rest to be closed as duplicates of that.

Comment: OK, I am sorry. I will fix it.