# What Python accessible tools can you use to generate XSD from an XML document?

Tags: python, xml, xsd, reverse-engineering

I'm looking for a tool that will play nicely with Python. 
Except for my Python requirement, my question is the same as this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74879/any-tools-to-generate-an-xsd-schema-from-an-xml-instance-document):

> "I am looking for a tool which will take an XML instance document and output a corresponding XSD schema."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there is no module that will run within your python program and do this conversion. But I see the problem of creating a XSD schema from XML as a tooling problem. It's the kind of functionality that I'll use once, to get a schema started but after that I'll be maintaining the schema myself. From reading a single XML file the XSD generator will create a starting point for a real schema, it cannot infer all the functionality and options offered by XSD. 
Basically, I don't see the need to have this conversion run as a module inside of my code, generating new XSDs every time the XML changes. After all, it's the schema that defines the XML not the other way around.

As end-user pointed out you could use xsd.exe but you might also want to look at other tools such as [trang](http://www.thaiopensource.com/relaxng/trang.html) (a bit old) for Java and [stylusstudio](http://www.stylusstudio.com/) (XML tool).

Answer (score 6):

According to the [PyCharm docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/generating-xml-schema-from-instance-document.html), PyCharm has a facility for this. This is not exactly accessible by a program as an API. You are probably better off using [XML Schema Learner](https://github.com/kore/XML-Schema-learner) as a separate program since it is a command line program (subprocess friendly!).

Comment: Just tested, and it has the option, works very well, thanks!

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/generating-xml-schema-from-instance-document.html , more information about conversion using Pycharm.

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for something like [pyxsd](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyxsd)? (primarily used for validation against a schema)  Or maybe [PyXB](http://pyxb.sourceforge.net/)?  (can generate classes based on xml)  Otherwise, I don't think there's a tool [yet] that will generate the schema from within Python.  Can you do it on demand using something like xsd.exe?  Does it have to be programmatic/repeatable?

Comment: It should be possible to do what I want and access tools like xsd.exe from within a Python program. I would preferred to use something like a Python module as it's easier to work with and more elegant a solution. pyxsd/PyXB don't seem to satisfy my requirements (as far as I can tell they don't have the ability to produce a schema, given an XML document).