# Getting autocompletion options for XML attribute values

Tags: xml, eclipse, xsd, intellisense, content-assist

How can I get autocompletion or intellisense or content assist options for XML attribute "values" using a preexsting sample XML(and nothing else) in some text editor?

For example If have

```
<samplexml attr="a">
</samplexml>
<samplexml attr="b">
</samplexml>
<samplexml attr="c">
</samplexml>
```

Then when I type `<samplexml attr=` I should be shown the options a,b and c

I would like the above in Eclipse, but if not Eclipse is there some other open source tool which can give me this?

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse XML editor would give you auto-complete if you have root node. The problem with this XML is it dont have root node

[image]

Refer http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_element

Comment: This gives logging only for elements and attributes not for attribute "values"

Comment: by values did you mean "a", "b" and "c"? If yes then I eclipse editor don't provide that :)

Comment: Yes I did mean "a" "b" and "c"

Comment: If you have XSD then it would work. Otherwise I guess you are out of luck with default editor.

Comment: Can I generate XSD in Eclipse? How do I generate XSD without using internet based tools, i.e. using some open source tool?

Comment: I am not aware of any tools for that. But I wont recommend that unless it is requried. you would spend more time generating it instead of typing.

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/74879/any-tools-to-generate-an-xsd-schema-from-an-xml-instance-document