# Get xml tree object by specifying part of its tag

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x

I was to obtain the node of the tag:

```
<helloworld>
...
</helloworld>
```

How do i use the .find() operation provided by the [The ElementTree XML API](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) if i only know half the tag characters?

In more detail i want `.find("(*)world")` and obtain the node of the helloworld tag

Comment: Is the example *really* something like `helloworld`, or is it something like `foo:world`?

Comment: it's just an example. The point is i want to mach with half the tag and get the node

Comment: Yes, but whether the division between the two halves is the namespace boundary is a critical detail (being a very common scenario, and thus a question we have good answers to already). If you're asking a more general question than you need, you'll get more general answers, which potentially also means answers that perform a lot worse.

Comment: not using namespaces

Comment: Relevant [parse the structure of the main item node without previously knowing its structure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53896422/7414759)