# Boost serialization with empty container

Tags: c++, xml, boost, xml-serialization, boost-serialization

I am using boost ( 1.69.0 ) serialization to generate an XML template file.
The result I want to achieve is unfortunately bad.
This is example code:

```
struct A
{
    struct B
    {

        int bInt;
        bool bBool;

    private:
        friend class boost::serialization::access;


        template < class Archive >
        void serialize( Archive& ar, const unsigned int version )
        {
            ar& BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP( bInt );
            ar& BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP( bBool );

        }
    };

    std::vector< B > aVector;
    int aInt;
    bool abool;

private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;

    template < class Archive >
    void serialize( Archive& ar, const unsigned int version )
    {
        ar& BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP( aVector );
        ar& BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP( aInt );
        ar& BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP( abool );

    }
};
```

And calling

```
void createXml( const std::filesystem::path& filePath )
{
    if (filePath.empty())
    {
        return;
    }

    A data;
    wofstream wofFile( filePath.c_str() );
    boost::archive::xml_woarchive warOutArchive( wofFile );
    warOutArchive << boost::serialization::make_nvp( "_Template", data );
}
```

Result:

```
<boost_serialization signature="serialization::archive" version="17">
<_Template class_id="0" tracking_level="0" version="0">
    <aVector class_id="1" tracking_level="0" version="0">
        <count>0</count>
        <item_version>0</item_version>
    </aVector>
    <aInt>-858993460</aInt>
    <abool>204</abool>
</_Template>
</boost_serialization>
```

As you can see, the template generates incorrectly. Content is missing

Everything works well. when I add an element to an empty vector.

`sData.aVector.push_back( { 5, true } );`

Result:

```
<boost_serialization signature="serialization::archive" version="17">
<_Template class_id="0" tracking_level="0" version="0">
    <aVector class_id="1" tracking_level="0" version="0">
        <count>1</count>
        <item_version>0</item_version>
        <item class_id="2" tracking_level="0" version="0">
            <bint>5</bint>
            <bbool>1</bbool>
        </item>
    </aVector>
    <aInt>-858993460</aInt>
    <abool>204</abool>
</_Template>
</boost_serialization>
```

Is there any way to generate an xml file template without adding elements to containers? I only need the document template/tree, no values.

Comment: But your 2 results are exactly the same (except for the item {5, true}). So what is missing from your output?

Comment: You're asking boost to serialize an empty vector. Why would it hallucinate an element that does not exist?

Comment: Isn't. In second result i have a output about bint and bbool. As I mentioned. I need a tree structure with all the nodes. I use these names later to validate the file that I am loading with the correct data.

Comment: @Botje That's the problem, I'm looking for a solution that will make this possible.  To create an xml template without values ​​and only nodes.

Comment: How many elements should the XML template specify for `aVector`, then?

Comment: @Botje You keep focusing on this particular example, which I just wanted to illustrate what I mean. I am looking for a way to get what I have written about several times. Not necessarily the way it's done. This was just needed to present the problem.

Comment: If your requirements do not allow you to provide a sample input object that results in the output you want, then you cannot use the boost::serialization library as is. Your only option is then to recreate what the boost library does as if it had a representative object.

Answer (score 0):

Do you ... just want to infer an XML schema for the file? Boost Serialization doesn't have this. You can however prepopulate all your members and then use an existing tool to infer a schema from the example output:

[Any tools to generate an XSD schema from an XML instance document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74879/any-tools-to-generate-an-xsd-schema-from-an-xml-instance-document)

To automatically prepopulate any container elements you could write a helper function like:

```cpp
namespace detail {
    /// simplistic trait to detect if a type is a container
    template <typename, typename Enable = void> struct is_container : std::false_type {};
    template <typename T>
    struct is_container<T,
                        decltype(                                  //
                            decltype(std::declval<T>().begin()){}, //
                            decltype(std::declval<T>().end()){},   //
                            decltype(std::declval<T>().size()){},  //
                            void())> : std::true_type {};

    // trivial archive implementation that just prepopulates container objects
    struct prepopulater {
        using is_saving  = std::true_type;
        using is_loading = std::false_type;
        template <class T> void          register_type() {}
        template <class Deduced> prepopulater& operator<<(Deduced&& v) {
            using T = std::decay_t<Deduced>;

            if constexpr (is_container<T>{}) {
                using V = std::decay_t<decltype(*v.begin())>;
                auto& mv = const_cast<T&>(v);
                std::cout << "Prepopulate " << boost::core::demangle(typeid(T).name()) << std::endl;
                mv.insert(mv.end(), V{});
            }
            using boost::serialization::serialize;
            constexpr auto IL = boost::serialization::implementation_level<T>::value;
            if constexpr (IL != boost::serialization::not_serializable &&
                          IL != boost::serialization::primitive_type) {
                auto& mv = const_cast<T&>(v);
                serialize(*this, mv, 0);
            }
            return *this;
        }
        template <class T> prepopulater& operator&(T&& v) { return *this << std ::forward<T>(v); }

        template <class T> prepopulater& operator<<(boost::serialization::nvp<T> t) {
            return *this << t.value();
        }
        template <class T> prepopulater& operator&(boost::serialization::nvp<T> t) {
            return *this << t.value();
        }

        void save_binary(void*, size_t){};
    };

} // namespace detail

template <typename Serializable> void prepopulate(Serializable& obj) { detail::prepopulater{} << obj; }
```

Note that this runs into trouble when you have recursive data structures, because it will run out of memory infinitely deepening. This, however, is the nature of the requirement that your question poses.

For example, replacing `int bInt` with `std::multiset<int> bInts` just for better demo:

**[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e5391271e80e81b9)**

```cpp
#include <boost/archive/xml_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/xml_oarchive.hpp>
// #include <boost/core/demangle.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/nvp.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/set.hpp>
#include <filesystem>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

namespace detail {
    /// simplistic trait to detect if a type is a container
    template <typename, typename Enable = void> struct is_container : std::false_type {};
    template <typename T>
    struct is_container<T,
                        decltype(                                  //
                            decltype(std::declval<T>().begin()){}, //
                            decltype(std::declval<T>().end()){},   //
                            decltype(std::declval<T>().size()){},  //
                            void())> : std::true_type {};

    // trivial archive implementation that just prepopulates container objects
    struct prepopulater {
        using is_saving  = std::true_type;
        using is_loading = std::false_type;
        template <class T> void          register_type() {}
        template <class Deduced> prepopulater& operator<<(Deduced&& v) {
            using T = std::decay_t<Deduced>;

            if constexpr (is_container<T>{}) {
                using V = std::decay_t<decltype(*v.begin())>;
                auto& mv = const_cast<T&>(v);
                // std::cout << "Prepopulate " << boost::core::demangle(typeid(T).name()) << std::endl;
                mv.insert(mv.end(), V{});
            }
            using boost::serialization::serialize;
            constexpr auto IL = boost::serialization::implementation_level<T>::value;
            if constexpr (IL != boost::serialization::not_serializable &&
                          IL != boost::serialization::primitive_type) {
                auto& mv = const_cast<T&>(v);
                serialize(*this, mv, 0);
            }
            return *this;
        }
        template <class T> prepopulater& operator&(T&& v) { return *this << std ::forward<T>(v); }

        template <class T> prepopulater& operator<<(boost::serialization::nvp<T> t) {
            return *this << t.value();
        }
        template <class T> prepopulater& operator&(boost::serialization::nvp<T> t) {
            return *this << t.value();
        }

        void save_binary(void*, size_t){};
    };

} // namespace detail

template <typename Serializable> void prepopulate(Serializable& obj) { detail::prepopulater{} << obj; }

struct A {
    struct B {
        std::multiset<int> bInts;
        bool               bBool;
        template <class Ar> void serialize(Ar& ar, unsigned) { ar& BOOST_NVP(bInts) & BOOST_NVP(bBool); }
    };

    std::vector<B> aVector;
    int            aInt;
    bool           abool;
    template <class Ar> void serialize(Ar& ar, unsigned) { ar& BOOST_NVP(aVector) & BOOST_NVP(aInt) & BOOST_NVP(abool); }
};

void createTemplateXml(std::filesystem::path const& filePath) {
    A data;
    prepopulate(data);

    std::ofstream ofFile(filePath);
    boost::archive::xml_oarchive(ofFile) << boost::serialization::make_nvp("_Template", data);
}

int main() {
    createTemplateXml("prepopulated.xml");
}
```

Which writes

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<!DOCTYPE boost_serialization>
<boost_serialization signature="serialization::archive" version="20">
<_Template class_id="0" tracking_level="0" version="0">
    <aVector class_id="1" tracking_level="0" version="0">
        <count>1</count>
        <item_version>0</item_version>
        <item class_id="2" tracking_level="0" version="0">
            <bInts>
                <count>1</count>
                <item_version>0</item_version>
                <item>0</item>
            </bInts>
            <bBool>0</bBool>
        </item>
    </aVector>
    <aInt>0</aInt>
    <abool>0</abool>
</_Template>
</boost_serialization>
```